# How can I Passing 'var' in foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, var

```
 class Writer
{
   public void Write( int i )
    {
    }
   public  void Write(IList l) 
    {
        foreach ( var i in l )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
            //Write( i );//CS1502
        }
    }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
        Writer t = new Writer();
        t.Write( array1 );
    }
}
```

print the type of var is 'System.Int32' and 'System.String'.Whats up with the loop.
Anyone can help me.

Comment: Your list can contain anything, while your `write` function only accepts integers...

Comment: Please give us more information about what you're *really* trying to do. You've already told us that the sequence can contain non-int values. Can it contain a mixture? Does the caller know the types?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to change `void Write(IList l)` to `void Write(IList<int> l)`.

**edit**

You could also add generics like this:

`void Write<T>(IList<T> l)` and `void Write<T>(T i)`

Comment: Or even just `IEnumerable<int>`...

Comment: but i also want to pass string [] or short[] to the Write(IList l).Thera are other overload methods like Write(short s ) ,Write( string s )

Comment: @user1747368 - ill have an update in a second

Answer (score 2):

Change the signature of `void Write(IList l)` to `void Write(IList<int> l)` instead.

The reason why it won't compile is because `IList` isn't generic and so the type of the items in your list are `object` however there is no overload of `Write` that accepts an `object`.

By changing the signature of `Write` you are telling the compiler that the items in your list are actually `int`, and so it resolves to the correct overload.

Alternatively change your `void Write(int i)` method to have the signature `void Write(object o)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

GetType prints the type of object of the variable. I assume you just want the value?

```
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` is **not** dynamic, the underlying type is defined at compile-time.

Read up on the `dynamic` keyword, or just use an `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: suggesting that he use `dynamic` here is not the right approach...

Comment: @Servy: Actually, given the comments on Daniel's answer, I think it's what he'll need anyway, given that he wants overload resolution to depend on the actual type...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes that was my point.

Comment: @JonSkeet He doesn't *need* dynamic.  For every `Write` method taking a single item he would simply need to add a corresponding `Write` method that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` where T is the type of the corresponding `Write` method.  Using `dynamic` would result in less lines of code, but it would still be poor design in my eyes.  Of course, the best case would be to refactor `Write` so that it could just accept an `object` or `string`, if at all possible.

Comment: @Servy: I suspect the OP really doesn't *want* to create an extra overload per collection type though. There may well be better approaches to the overall problem, of course... we don't have enough context.

Comment: @Servy: Also, your Write method taking a sequence wouldn't work for the scenario where there's mixed data - a single sequence containing (say) strings and ints.

Comment: @JonSkeet True.  At this point I'd say the OP hasn't provided enough information to answer the question, but chances are there is better fundamental approach to solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just use foreach(object i in l)? var doesn't have any benefits in this chase.
use generics like "Daniel A. White" said if you all have a list with one type.

If you want to use a list with multiple type keep our methods, but replace var with object, get the type of the current object and and write the string like you want.